# what is faster? 1) adding elements to treeset VS 2)adding to Hashset and then sorting hashset elements

Tags: java, collections

I would like to know which collection gives better performance. If required result is to obtain non repeated sorted collection.

1. treeSet - O(nlogn)
2. hashSet - add n elements gives O(n) and then sort using collection.sort() gives O(nlogn)

theoretically both gives same but wants to know if it really makes any difference if passed input length is more than 100K. Also what could be the reason?

Comment: Try it and then tell us ;)

Comment: lol, I tried and got 2nd approach more faster for 100 inputs. But couldnt understand why.

Comment: Because the overhead of managing a Red-Black tree is not small.

Comment: @DaenKhaleesi I'm a little curious how exactly you are using method `Collections.sort` with a `HashSet`, seeing as the former requires a `List`, which the latter does not implement?

Answer (score 2):

Collections.sort() uses TimSort internally which is likely a little faster than adding elements into a TreeSet.  More importantly though, the memory overhead for HashSet and Collections.sort() should be lower than TreeSet.